# Change Background color of Gtk.Entry in Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk3

I want to change the background color of my Gtk.Entry widget to red, to display that there's an error in this field.

I've found several methods how to accomplish this.

```
entry.modify_bg -> no change
entry.override_bg -> no change
entry.modify_base -> no change
```

Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `entry.override_background_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, ...)` (not `override_bg()`) or you can create some CSS:

```
provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
provider.load_from_data('.entry { background: red; }')
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Comment: The CssProvider is the way I got it working. The override_background_color (which i've meant) was although not working